# Android databinding / MVVM pattern: computing view color based off Enum

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

I have a class with the following enum and variables:

```
enum class ExerciseSetState {
    NOT_STARTED, PASSED, FAILED
}

@Entity
class ExerciseEntity(
        ... 
        @Ignore var setState: ExerciseSetState = ExerciseSetState.NOT_STARTED
        ....
 )
```

And in my databinding layout, I want to set the color based on this state variable:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_exer_rep_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@{String.valueOf(exercise.setReps)}"
        android:backgroundColor="@{exercise.setState == ExerciseSetState.PASSED? (Color.GREEN : exercise.setState == ExerciseSetState.FAILED ? Color.RED: Color.TRANSPARENT )}"/>
```

Unfortunately I have this pretty horrible ternary expression in order to compute the color based off the value.

What is the idiomatic way of implementing this?

Comment: see [Binding adapters](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it simple with adapter:

```
 @BindingAdapter("xmlTag")
        public static void bindColor(TextView textView, @Nullable ExerciseSetState state) {
            //switch state and set the value
        }
```

in xml:

```
app:xmlTag="@{exercies.setState}"
```

Comment: Thank you.
Where should I put the code for the binding adapter? It doesnt seem to fit in my WorkoutActivity or my WorkoutViewModel..

Comment: just create a separate class for it

Comment: I did that. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Converter class and use it for converting enum to color

**Layout:**

```
<import type="*.Converter"/>
...

android:background="@{Converter.enumToColor(context, exercise.setState)}"
```

**Converter Class:**

```
class Converter {

    fun enumToColor(context: Context ,enum: ExerciseSetState) : Int {
        return when (enum){
            ExerciseSetState.NOT_STARTED -> getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent)
            ExerciseSetState.PASSED -> getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent)
            ExerciseSetState.FAILED -> getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent)
        }
    }
}
```

**getColor** helper method:

```
fun getColor(context: Context, colorId: Int): Int {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        context.resources.getColor(colorId, null)
    } else {
        context.resources.getColor(colorId)
    }
}
```

and better to change setState to getState in here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply specify colors in the enum. Because colors relate to enum.

```
enum class ExerciseSetState(var color: Int) {
    NOT_STARTED(Color.TRANSPARENT), PASSED(Color.GREEN), FAILED(Color.RED)
}
```

and

```
android:backgroundColor="@{exercise.setState.color}"
```

Comment: And change `setState` to `getState` or state for better naming convention.